# Git checkout from git://* not working

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am trying to checkout from the following git://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git but this fails, with this error message:

```
Cloning into cloud9...
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
```

When I checkout from https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git it works without any problems.

I am working on Ubuntu Desktop 32bit 11.04. An upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 is no option.

Comment: `git clone git://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git` works for me. Could be a problem with your firewall?

Comment: Are you using some kind of proxy to connect to the internet? If so, then this might be a problem.

Comment: Yeah that might be the reason. I'll try it later at home, cause currently I'm at work. Thx.

Comment: Ok, I tryed it at home and it works. Thx to all :)

Answer (score 0):

If a proxy is involve, at the very least you would need to set (at work, not home) the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY`

The alternative is to use the [`git config http.proxy` setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy).

> In addition to the syntax understood by `curl`, it is possible to specify a proxy string with a user name but no password, in which case git will attempt to acquire one in the same way it does for other credentials.